# Free ASF (2 video streams and 1 audio stream) to FLV converter?

Tags: flv, converters, asf

I have ***.asf*** files. All of them have *2 video streams* and *1 audio stream* in it. I need to extract that ***.asf*** into ***2 .flv*** files (first one is video stream, second one is second video + audio stream).

Is there some free program with funcitonality like this where I can choose which streams I want to extract/convert to ***.flv***. I've tried at least 15 programs and all of them open my ***.asf*** file and offer me to convert it but none of them "knows" about that second video stream. Some programs opens my ***.asf*** and in external window open second video stream but not offering any functionallity to it. It's like they aren't aware of that second video stream.

I don't want to write my own program with Xuggle if I don't need to.

Thank You,

Dino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer this old question. On Windows download the program [Haali Muxer](http://haali.su/mkv/) and split the file as you want. Then there are many converters to .flv format but now there is only one video and audio stream in source file after splitting it with Haali Muxer.